# Mixture of binomial distributions

Tags: binomial-distribution, mixture-distribution, identifiability

I am experimenting with a mixture of binomial models. Consider a binary variable $y_i$. Furthermore, there are two sub-groups in the population (not known a priori and not observable): $z_i=0$ or $z_i=1$. 
For one sub-group of the population, the following holds true:
\begin{equation}
 P(y_i=1|z_i=0)= \xi,
\end{equation}
with $\xi$ a fixed probability (not estimated by the model but provided by the user). For the other sub-group, we have:
\begin{equation}
 P(y_i=1|z_i=1)= g_i = g(x_i' \theta_g) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-x_i'\theta_g)},
\end{equation}
with $x_i$ a vector of independent variables (including intercept), $\theta_g$ a parameter vector and $g_i$ short-hand notation.

The probability that an observation belongs to a certain sub-population is equal to:
\begin{equation}
 P(z_i=1)= h_i=h(\tilde{x}_i' \theta_h) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\tilde{x}_i'\theta_h)},
\end{equation}
with $\tilde{x}_i$ a vector of independent variables and $\theta_h$ the corresponding parameter vector. Note that, in general, $\tilde{x}_i$ may be different from $x_i$. In a special case, $\tilde{x}_i$ only contains an intercept, in which we have fixed mixing proportions (I have experimented with both, and both lead to the same problem, described below - let variant 1 be the one with intercept only, and variant 2 the one with more independent variables).

The problem occurs when trying to estimate this model. I have implemented the EM algorithm (double/triple/quadruple checked, I am 95% sure the math is correct), but it seems my model is not identifiable (neither of both variants). When creating a contour plot (or plotting the surface) for two independent variables, there is no 'peak' but rather a 'ridge'.

I can intuitively understand this when looking at:
\begin{equation}
P(y_i=1) = h_i\cdot g_i+(1-h_i) \cdot \xi.
\end{equation}
I can imagine that one could increase $h_i$ and decrease $g_i$ in the right proportions and arrive at the same probability $P(y_i=1)$. And then probably this holds true for the LL as well.

I have started to look in the literature for solutions for this problem, but I did not find a final answer yet. Is there a solution for this identifiability problem (at least I think that is the problem)? Could some additional constraints solve the problem, or is there another solution? I it, after all, possible to create a mixture of binomial distributions?

I hope my explanation is clear.

Comment: How does your model differ from zero-inflated binomial regression?

Comment: As far as I understood, zero-inflated binomial regression is for count data with excessive zeros. This model is for binary data (yes/no) and the class distribution is not necessarily very skwew. 
From what I have read, I think a mixture of binomial models is never identifiable, but I am not sure. Also, I am wondering, if the above is true, whether there are workarounds for that (extra constraints or something).

Comment: But isn't that close to what your model is doing--accounting for either too many or too few zeros?

Comment: The main goal of my model is to describe two types of subgroups (the z-variable, unobservable), and then to have a different model for y in the sub-group. The reason is that I would like to do some kind of segmentation while estimating the model. 
I am afraid however that a mixture of binomial models does not work, and I could not find any "fix" for this issue (yet).

Comment: [Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1017939148) is a paper on binomial mixtures